# What makes TLS client key exchange failed

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have one php application using LDAP (via apache2.4) to authority user, but i get below error.

---

### LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed

After sometime i finally realize it may handshake failed for TLS, i tried to tracing and found after "server hello done", the "client key exchange" is missing, i am new to TLS, appreate if you can tell me where can i find the root cause and how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: I don't know what is making these network captures, it's not a tool I'm familiar with. It looks like the client closes the TCP connection without a proper orderly TLS shutdown. If I were to take a wild guess with no real evidence to back it up, I'd guess there's a problem with one or more of the server's certificates and/or with your configuration of the client. There not enough information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help.
Finally i know the reason it on Windows itself, other system log have found in Event viewer. Seems FIPS have something then it cannot create credentials while creating TLS connections.

A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential.

Then i follow the thing and changed local security poily it works.